# WPF Style template with recource dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates

Im new to this so maybe its a very simple thing that might be wrong...

I try to use a style ResourceDictionary but when I try to use it in my application it doesn't work.
This is the directory:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key ="DarkBackground" StartPoint ="0,0" EndPoint =" 1,1">
    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color =" #FF333344"></GradientStop>
    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color =" #FF666677"></GradientStop>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="StandardBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFBBBBBB" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

The Application.xaml looks like that:

```
<Application x:Class="MyApplication.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="\src\GUI\MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source ="StyleTemplates.xaml"> </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Entrys in the MainWindow:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
```

In my MainWindow I want to do something like:

```
<TabItem Header="Project config" Background="{StaticResource StandardBackground}" Margin="-2,-2,2,0" IsEnabled="{Binding ToolPreference.ProjectLoaded}">
```

What do I have to do next to get the styles as static recources in my MainWindow.xaml and also in all other availabe windows?

In my MainWindow.xaml I can now see the "StandardBackground" when I try this:

```
<TabItem Header="Project config" Background="{StaticResource x:StandardBackground}" Margin="-2,-2,2,0" IsEnabled="{Binding ToolPreference.ProjectLoaded}">
```

When I add the "x:" I get a dropdown with StandardBackground and DarkBackground. But the I get the error:(translated from german to english) "The resource: x:StandardBackground could not be resolved"

Comment: You have to merge ResourceDictionary like this http://prntscr.com/5sdssx

Comment: Ok I tried but it's still not working...

Comment: Tabitem background you can change by editing its style.see this http://prntscr.com/5se761.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your XAML.  I suspect your StandardBackground and DarkBackground resources would work fine on other controls.  Your issue in this case is that the Background property of a TabItem has no effect.  You need to look into styling the TabControl to achieve the look you want.

To verify that your styles are at least accessible, you could try the following XAML change:

```
<TabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
        <TextBox Text="Project config" Background="{StaticResource StandardBackground}" />
    </TabItem.Header>
</TabItem>
```

Comment: It works fine on a textbox. I will have a look at the TabContol specifc background...thanks a lot.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source ="StyleTemplates.xaml"> </ResourceDictionary>
       </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I tried but it's still not working, do I maybe have to add something in my "MainWindow.xaml"?!

Comment: It is not necessary to merge dictionaries unless you need to use more than one.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry your problem wasn't clear enough for me.